# Use git squash in branch already pushed and work with colaborators

Tags: git, push, squash, multiple-users

It is not clear to me in previous answers if the following commands affect teamwork:

```
git checkout -b featureX
// add some changes ..
git commit ...
// add some changes ..
git commit ...
// add some changes ..
git commit ...
// add some changes ..
git commit ...
git push ..

and another partner does the following:

git pull origin featureX
// add some changes ..
git commit ...
// add some changes ..
git commit ...
...
git rebase -i featureX ~ 5 featureX
git push origin + featureX

and I then:

git pull
git checkout featureX
git rebase master
// or
git merge master
```

This creates problems?

If so, what is the way to work as a team with a large number of commits and then merge in a legible manner?

Answer (score 2):

The step that would create problems for you is this part:

```
git rebase -i featureX ~ 5 featureX
git push origin + featureX

and I then:

git pull
```

The reason it *could* create problems is if you modified code since your last push, your code could be based on commits that are no longer in the commit history (they could have been modified or removed by your teammate during the interactive rebase). This is not an "unrecoverable" problem, but it can lead to confusion, duplicated commits, bad merge resolutions, etc. So the simple rule of thumb is - don't rewrite history that other people might have used as a starting point for their work.

Here are a few other ideas which might help you organize your commits without running into git history problems:

- Run `git rebase -i` on your own branch *before* pushing your work up to the shared repository.
- OR Wait until *everyone* is done committing to your branch, and then do `git rebase -i` on everyone's work before merging to master. This is safe because you know that nobody will be doing more work on the commits you're about to modify.
- OR Squash the branch when you merge it to master (GitHub (and most other hosts) have an option for this).
- OR Don't worry so much about your messy history, or just work on making your initial commits cleaner.
- OR Work on a branch that only you will use (for example, `feature1-alan`). You can push and pull to/from this branch as many times as you want and also on different computers as necessary. You can also squash commits and force push this branch whenever you want - as long as you don't have your own unmerged work hanging out on a different computer. You can merge this branch to the team's branch `feature`, `master`, or whatever after you've squashed and are happy with the way your commits look.

Comment: Another option is to squash the commits, push the branch, and then get everyone to agree that the squashed branch is now master, renaming the branch at that point. This is impractical for more than a few participants.

Comment: 1- I do it whenever I can, but the problem is that I use two computers.
I make too many commits for power outages, so I can complete my work on the secondary notebook. (The main one is desktop)

2- I think it can give margin for error.  

3- I think this is the way.  

4- It is ideal, but the power cut limits me.

Comment: If you're worried about losing work because of changing computers, power outages, etc, it's always OK to squash a branch even after you've pushed _as long as you're the only one working on that branch_. So you could also consider making a "personal" branch on GitHub (or on your own fork on GitHub) and only merging that to a place where other people would work on it after you're done squashing. I'll add this as a 5th option above.

Comment: So, to simplify:
The problem that I raise in the question would not affect me if only I work in that branch (then I can merge "develop" or "master" in a calm way and that the others continue from there).
But does it also create problems for me if I use two different computers in the process? I do not understand where the problem of references is created, apologies.

Comment: Let's say your last commit is commit `a`. Now, let's say that on computer 1 you make commit `b` (after commit `a`), and on computer 2 you squash `a` into some previous commits. The problem is that `b` is based on `a`, but `a` no longer exists (because it was re-written during the squash). As long as you avoid creating commit `b` and re-writing history on commit `a` at the same time (whether it's you or someone else doing the committing), there is no problem.

Comment: And when you are the only person working on a particular branch, it's easy for you to ensure this. When multiple people are working on a branch, it's still possible to do this, but you need to communicate well and sync up your work, as Joe pointed out.